# Computing odds ratio confidence interval directly vs fitting logistic regression model

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, odds-ratio, asymptotics

If I have two binary variables. I can compute the odds ratio and its confidence interval directly from the data ([See here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_freq_a0000000565.htm) and [here](http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/QuantCore/PH717_ComparingFrequencies/PH717_ComparingFrequencies8.html)).

Alternatively, I can fit a logistic regression model and compute the odds ratio and confidence interval from the parameter estimate and its SE.

**Will these two methods produce the same odds ratio and confidence interval?**

If the answer is "not necessarily", why? Both of these confidence intervals are based on asymptotics. **Will they produce the same results asymptotically?**